# Scala new line without regex?

Tags: scala

I am trying to insert a new line into a string in scala.  I've been reading around and it seems to not be as straight forward as java or C++.

my problem is i have a class called usedCar and Im overriding the toString method which is a 1 liner.

```
override def toString = ("Make: " + _carMake +  "\nYear of Car: " + _yearOfCar + "\nVin Number: " + _vinNumber + "\nOdometer Mileage: " + _odometerMileage + "\nCondition of Car: " + _carCondition + "\nBest Price: " + _bestPrice + "\nAsking Price: " + askingPrice);
```

if someone can tell me how to get new lines in that toString method I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: well that is one of the issues which i just corrected but it doesnt split up the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You're using the wrong kind of slash.  You want a backslash (`\n`) not a forward slash (`/n`).</s>  The question has since been edited.

And if you are on Windows, you really want `\r\n` instead.  There are better ways of deciding which one to use, as Jarrod mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

The escape code in Java for a new line is `\n`.

In your original question before the edit you have `/n` which wasn't correct.

The idiomatic way to do this is to assign `sys.props("line.separator")` to a variable and append that instead.

A more modern idiomatic way to do this would be to use `String.format()` and build your String that way and supply the `sys.props("line.separator")` as well.